# Squid Rotating Exit IPs with cache_peer

Tags: squid

I am trying to duplicate the configuration described in this blog post.

http://www.everydayinternetstuff.com/2011/03/squid-random-outgoing-ipinterface-selection/

This technique as I understand it is supposed to trick squid into thinking it's both a parent and a cache_peer thus allowing you to roll exit IPs from a single instance.

Using this configuration I have been able to exit the IPs that I enter on, but I am unable to rotate exit IPs when entering .

The error page being reported is an Access Denied error page from squid cache.

I'd appreciate any assistance or suggestions. Also if anyone has a working configuration done a different way, I'd appreciate hearing those suggestions as well.

```
http_port <entry ip>:3128
http_port <exit1>:3128
http_port <exit2>:3128
http_port <exit3>:3128


auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/squid_passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm ProxyBox
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl ncsaauth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsaauth

acl src_01 src <exit1>
acl src_02 src <exit2>
acl src_03 src <exit3>

tcp_outgoing_address <exit1> src_01
tcp_outgoing_address <exit2> src_02
tcp_outgoing_address <exit3> src_03

acl first_req src 127.0.0.0/8
acl second_req src <exitnet>/29

cache_peer <exit1> parent 3128 0 round-robin no-query login=proxyadmin:password
cache_peer <exit2> parent 3128 0 round-robin no-query login=proxyadmin:password
cache_peer <exit3> parent 3128 0 round-robin no-query login=proxyadmin:password

cache_peer_access <exit1> allow first_req
cache_peer_access <exit2> allow first_req
cache_peer_access <exit3> allow first_req

cache_peer_access <exit1> deny second_req
cache_peer_access <exit2> deny second_req
cache_peer_access <exit3> deny second_req

never_direct allow first_req
never_direct deny second_req
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the configuration described in that link is a big mess. Use a standard Squid configuration and use iptables to distribute the load between your IPs:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.201
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.202
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.203
```

Those IPs should be your local IPs.

Regards,
 Diego